# Multithreaded TCP server in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I need to get up and running quickly with a MT TCP server implemented in C#, as a proof of concept. I am looking for an open source implementation of such a multi-threaded TCP server in C#.

I came across this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2866/Multi-threaded-NET-TCP-Server-Examples), but it is almost a decade old!. I can't seem to find anything more recent. Is anyone aware of a more recent implementation of a MT TCP server?

Comment: This is just lazy, i spend 2 seconds on codeproject and found a ton of new samples. Also not even posting whats wrong the old code is bad

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nclsamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Socket%20Performance

Comment: @EKS: care to share those links here? I can't find any **MT** TCP Servers more recent than the link I sent.

Comment: @the_ajp: Not **MT** though is it?. Also, in the comments, a user was complaining that the code leaked memory ... I think I'll pass on that.

Comment: Is asynchronous isn't it that implies at least a couple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relatively complete sample of a highly scaleable TCP server at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx.

Comment: Not a multithreaded server. I guess I'll just have to use the decade old code for now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; it is highly multithreaded and uses IO completion ports under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll need to take a closer look at the code. Thanks for the link.